# What's wrong with my relay? (Consensus Weight Jumping Around)

Tags: relays, guard

I recently set up (19 days ago or so) a new, non-exit, relay. It's gotten the guard, stable and fast flags, but it's consensus weight keeps jumping up and down for some reason (my understanding is that it should keep rising slowly after getting the guard flag). /var/log/tor/notices.log doesn't show anything of interest (I was getting an error due to too little CPU/RAM for the traffic load I was seeing, but I doubled the size of the VM after around 2 weeks, which got rid of that error).

Relay in question:
https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/4CA64E677ECFF23B138CFE70A6A02E94BDF3A805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consensus weight is just an indication of the measured throughput of the relay. It's the "Observed Bandwidth", as measured by Bandwidth Authority relays. *(For more on Bandwidth Authorities, see [TorFlow](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torflow.git/tree/NetworkScanners/BwAuthority/README.spec.txt).)*

For example, if we look at your relay just now on Atlas, it shows:

> **Consensus Weight**
>
> 7858

And if we look at the descriptor of the relay, it shows:

```
r grumpytechie1 TKZOZ37P8jsTjP5wpqAulL3zqAU 1z/zwwjEv98DFWqRnF2vt4BnYL0 2018-02-27 18:03:15 185.103.110.248 9001 9030
s Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
w Bandwidth=7858
p reject 1-65535
```

We see that the `Bandwidth=` value is the same as it's "*Consensus Weight*".

This is documented in [`dir-spec.txt`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2245):

```
"w" SP "Bandwidth=" INT [SP "Measured=" INT] [SP "Unmeasured=1"] NL

    [At most once.]

    An estimate of the bandwidth of this relay, in an arbitrary
    unit (currently kilobytes per second).  Used to weight router
    selection. See section 3.4.2 for details on how the value of
    Bandwidth is determined in a consensus.
```